# voting to reopen

Tags: discussion, re-open

When you vote to reopen a closed question, you're not prompted to enter your reason for thinking it ought to be reopened.  Where is the appropriate forum for that?  Here in meta, or in the comments under the question, or what?

(I voted to reopen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247644/show-that-int-limits-infty-infty-mathbbe-x2-mathrmdx) question, and posted my reason in the comments.)

Comment: See also the [Requests for Reopen Votes thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424/242)

Comment: This is related and needs to be re-opened: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846746/79069, please vote up/reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Putting a comment on the question is what I am used to seeing.  However, if there is an issue that might require some discussion, then also addressing that issue here would be appropriate.